# My pc won't boot

Tags: boot

I booted up my pc and relized all my personal data
Was missing. All my photos,videos, programs, even some
Windows programs including wizards. The next day when I
Tried booting up the computer said it can't because it was
Missing an essential drive. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you write down the exact error message? What OS exactly? You need to give a lot more information if you are going to get help.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, it sounds as if your drive is quickly going bad.  As @KCotreau mentions, we'll need more info to help, but I wouldn't hold out much hope.  I suggest leaving it off until you can  get someone to look at it.